# I installed Python 3.6.0 from the official website. But when i run python -- version on my bash shell .it say 2.7.1. And i don't know why

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XVti.png)
[image]

This is from my bash shell. but the version i downloaded is 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

you may have two versions of python try using `python3 --version`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch Python3, you have to mention `python3` precisely. You can set default python version as 3 but Most of the python developers would suggest you to create a virtualenv with default environment as Python3.

How to: https://gist.github.com/Geoyi/d9fab4f609e9f75941946be45000632b

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the blog post from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/).

But I would recommend not using the last part to update the default python3 alternative to python3.6, due to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.6/+bug/1631367).

Answer (score 0):

python 2.7 is default python in Mac.

use `python3` to run your python 3.0 script.

Comment: if you say 2.7 is default , then how should i get to use it . Because my IDLE says python version 3.6.4( the one downloaded by me). Sorry i new to these stuffs!

Comment: you can type `python3 test.py` on your console to run your code. test.py is your python script name.